# How to save drawing without its background?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics, save

Currently i am trying to draw some line in my iPad screen and i am able to do so.

I am following this code:

[iPad (very) simple drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956202/ipad-very-simple-drawing)

So currently if i am trying to save the drawing

I cannot save the drawing without its background,It saves the whole screen i.e. that drawing and its background.So how can i save only lines not its background.

Any sample application or tutorial available for this?

Comment: Which bit of the code in the link are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Whatever graphics editor you might have available, use it to identify that background color as **transparent**, which will accomplish that.